# Increase KeywordQuery QueryText max length in SP 2010

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, fulltextsqlquery, keywordquery

I am using SharePoint Server 2010. I faced some difficulties with the Core Search Results Web Part. The issue was that my query length was to be about 2500 characters. This long query served to filter the search results by some managed properties. According to this link http://web.archive.org/web/20120306120252/http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/11/fulltextsqlquery-with-querytext-max.html I got the limit of the query - 1024 characters. So, I had the next cases.

1. Increase the limit of the query. I gave attention to this matter spending hours with the reflector. It seems to me, that this limit is sewed up very deeply and there is no chance to change it.
2. Use FullTextSqlQuery, which has 4096 limit characters. This amount would be enough to resolve the problem. But I haven't found the way how to bind it to Core Results Web Part. I saw many solutions with reflection for MOSS, but didn't anything for SP 2010.

Is there a way to increase the max limit of the query in KeywordQuery or bind FullTextSqlQuery to Core Results Web part?